# How could I paging by twice top process without sort condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, paging

I can I get paging without sort condition?

I know if there is sort condition you can use

```
select top m_page_size * from (
     select top m_end_row_number * from (
           /*select part*/   
      ) as t_first_result
      order by m_some_row asc
)as t_second_result
order by m_some_row desc
```

but for some conditions there is no sort conditions in my application, so how could we use the twice top method, is there a solid column just like row_number in ORACLE for sorting?

if twice top method can not work, is there any other method for such a case?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then answer might be below::
Let me know your comments.

```
select top m_page_size 1,* from (
     select top m_end_row_number 1,* from (
           /*select part*/   
      ) as t_first_result
      order by 1 asc
)as t_second_result
order by 1 desc
```

Go through the following link, and try to use FETCH NEXT and give try.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Comment: No, the m_end_row_number is a certain number, if the page size is 20
1st page: m_page_size: 20; m_end_row_number:20.
2rd page: m_page_size: 20; m_end_row_number:40
....

Comment: Then how you are deciding that value for m_end_row_number ?  ?

Comment: from the web site, they will provide paging information include the m_end_row_number. so here the m_end_row_number is not a column

Comment: Can you provide some example with data then it will be easy to understand.

Comment: when web require the 3rd page of report, the sql script is `select top 20 * from (select top 60 * from (select id, name from user_info) as first_result order by id asc)as second_result order by id desc`